# keras.Model ValueError/TypeError when output is from customized layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm attempting to model a function as a Keras Functional model combined with a customized Keras `Layer` class. The idea is to simply have the Keras layer's `call` method use a predefined function. The function will take as input a given tensor, say `tensor1`, and compute a certain dot product for every value `t` in `tensor1`. The dot product relies on tensors (vectors) of different lengths, but the output is a tensor (vector) of the same length as `tensor1`.

When passing `tensor1` into the function `TheFunction(tensor)` (defined below), it returns the output I expected. Moreover, when building the `TheFunctionLayer` object and passing in `tensor1`, the output is also as expected, being the same as that of `TheFunction(tensor1)`.

The issue arises when I try to use Keras's Functional model on the same thing. I'm trying to have it so that I can build the model object and pass `tensor1` into it. However, when attempting to do build the object, I get a `ValueError` regarding the dimensions of the tensors at play in the dot product. But if I make one small change to the output declaration in the definition of the model, I get a `TypeError`. Below is my source code and the issues that happen as they arise:

Imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Layer
import numpy as np
```

Tensors involved:

```
tensor1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
tensor1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor1, dtype=tf.float32)

tensor2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
tensor2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor2, dtype=tf.float32)

tensor3 = [6,7,8,9,10]
tensor3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor3, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The dot product function:

```
def TheFunction(tensor):
    tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor)
    def prod_term(t):
        return tensor3*t
    
    def dot(t):
        return tf.tensordot(tensor2,prod_term(t),axes=1)
    
    return tf.map_fn(lambda t: dot(t), tensor)
```

Result of  into the dot product function (no issues with dimensions):

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 130.,  260.,  390.,  520.,  650.,  780.,  910., 1040., 1170.,
       1300.], dtype=float32)>
```

The customized Keras layer (only `call`, no `__init__` needed):

```
class TheFunctionLayer(Layer):
    
    def call(self,tensor):
        return TheFunction(tensor)
```

Result of `TheFunctionLayer()(tensor1)` (again, no issues with dimensions):

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([ 130.,  260.,  390.,  520.,  650.,  780.,  910., 1040., 1170.,
       1300.], dtype=float32)>
```

The Keras Functional model:

```
def TheFunctionModel(input_shape):
    x = Input(shape=input_shape)
    y = TheFunctionLayer()(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    
    return model
```

Result of building model object `TheFunctionModel(tf.shape(tensor1))` (conflict with dimensions):

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 10 for '{{node the_function_layer_19/map/while/mul}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT](the_function_layer_19/map/while/mul/x, the_function_layer_19/map/while/TensorArrayV2Read/TensorListGetItem)' with input shapes: [5], [10].
```

What can possibly be going on here? I'm still new to the way TensorFlow and Keras works, but it seems like if the the output of my function works and has no conflict with tensor dimensions, why does trying to build the model object give me this dimensionality issue?

The other thing I'll add is the `TypeError` I get when changing the output `y = TheFunctionLayer()(x)` in the definition of `TheFunctionModel` to `y = TheFunctionLayer().call(x)`:

```
def TheFunctionModel(input_shape):
    x = Input(shape=input_shape)
    y = TheFunctionLayer().call(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    
    return model
```

Result of `TheFunctionModel(tf.shape(tensor1))` (`TypeError` occurs instead of original `ValueError`):

```
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 10) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.convert_to_tensor')> with type KerasTensor
```

If changing the output in the model definition is the way to get rid of the value error, then I'm not sure I understand the type error I get and how to fix it.

Suggestions and or solutions to the first value error or even the second type error are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the batch dimension and that is why it is not working. You will have to rewrite `TheFunction` like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Layer
import numpy as np

tensor2 = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=tf.float32)

tensor3 = tf.constant([6,7,8,9,10], dtype=tf.float32)

def TheFunction(tensor):
    
    def prod_term(t):
        return tensor3*t
    
    def dot(t):
        return tf.tensordot(tensor2,prod_term(t),axes=1)
    
    e = tf.zeros_like(tensor, dtype=tf.float32)
    i = tf.constant(0)

    while_condition = lambda i, e, tensor: tf.math.less(i, tf.shape(tensor)[0])
    def body(i, ta, tensor):
      tensor_shape = tf.shape(tensor)
      j = tf.repeat([i], tensor_shape[-1])
      indices = tf.stack([j, tf.range(tensor_shape[-1])], axis=1)
      ta = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tf.cast(ta, dtype=tf.float32), indices, tf.map_fn(lambda t: dot(t), tensor[i]))
      return tf.add(i, 1), ta, tensor
    _, e, _ = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, loop_vars=(i, e, tensor))
    return e
```

The `tf.while_loop` ensures that each sample in a batch is calculated independently of the others.

Your model:

```
tensor1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
tensor1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(tensor1, dtype=tf.float32)

class TheFunctionLayer(Layer):
    
    def call(self,tensor):
        return TheFunction(tensor)

def TheFunctionModel(input_shape = (10, )):
    x = Input(shape=input_shape)
    y = TheFunctionLayer()(x)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
    
    return model

model = TheFunctionModel()
print(model(tf.expand_dims(tensor1, axis=0)))
```

```
tf.Tensor([[ 130.  260.  390.  520.  650.  780.  910. 1040. 1170. 1300.]], shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. However, when I try to generalize this to other similar problems, I still get some of the same issues as before. Some have to do with inconsistent dtypes, but when I fix that, new ValueErrors emerge. Oh well, I suppose I've done all I can do in that regard. I'll keep wrestling with it. Nonetheless, I appreciate your response; it's been very helpful!